# Как добавить кнопку в конец разворачивоемой группы ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Пытался добавить как футер(listView.addFooterView(footerView);), но это работает в случае если нужно добавить кнопку "More" после всех групп. В моем же случае мне нужно добавить кнопку непосредственно в конце развернутой группы после всех отображенных элементов. Сама группа в адаптере, в методе (getGroupView)) является обыкновенным View и у меня не получается добавить к ней футер. Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему.

Comment: Нулевой элемент списка в child это хедер и последний элемент это футер вот и все решение. В адаптере отслеживайте начало и конец списка в метод getChildView (могу ошибаться с названием) и ставьте вашу разметку. Я просто с планшета, так бы добавил ответ.